# What is font's name of attach image's text?

Tags: font-identification

everyone..
please help me identify font name of below attach image.

Which use is of font's name in this attach image's text.

Advance thanks

[image]

Comment: have you tried [our font-identification resorces](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info)?

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's [Refreshment Stand](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fontdiner/refreshment-stand/regular/).

[image]

But please, in the future use a service such as [What The Font](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) or similar before you ask someone else to do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

The font is "Halo Handletter"

http://www.dafont.com/halohandletter.font?text=Designer+Family+Dental
[image]